# verificador de correo electrónico

Tags: java

tengo este método:

```
public static boolean esEmail(String correo) 
{
    Pattern pat = null;
    Matcher mat = null;        
    pat = Pattern.compile("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,3})$");
    mat = pat.matcher(correo.trim());
    if (mat.find()) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

pero quiero que me valide si la dirección que me proporcionan contiene "sitio.com" luego del @

yo le modifique el pat:

```
pat = Pattern.compile("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@+(\\sitio.com)$");
```

me pueden decir si esta correcto el cambio, o que necesita ser modificado porque cuando lo utilizo, solo me devuelve falso

Gracias

Comment: el error se presenta cuando le puse "//"sitio.com

Comment: saludos revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14817284/5215609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería ser simplemente:

```
  pat = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@+sitio.com");
```

para incluir direcciones que puedan contener "." pero que contengan caracteres de a-z (minúsculas, no estoy seguro si esto lo deseas así), números de 0-9, "@" y el dominio.

Te sugiero agregar que también acepte letras mayúsculas:

```
 pat = Pattern.compile("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@+sitio.com");
```

En esta pregunta en el sitio en inglés puedes ver varios métodos:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817182/validate-only-a-specific-email-with-regex-in-java/14817284#14817284